# question about eulerian trail and edge disjoint

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a connected graph with exactly two odd degree verticies u and v where $deg(u)\ge 3$ and $deg(v)\ge 3$. Prove or disprove

a. There exist two edge disjoint u-v trails in G.

I have to show this if false but I cannot come up with a counte example.

Comment: What graphs have you tried?

Comment: I try K2,3 but it did not work

Comment: You're clearly going to need vertices that are connected to u but not v, and vice versa.

Comment: So make a graph so that all path from u to v must go through a certain edge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

..............................................................................

Comment: oh ok that makes sense